# Jquery time format using 00

Tags: jquery, time

anybody have a reference when I type :

```
24:19:01
```

Automatically in the form, will convert it with:

```
00:19:01
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually day consist of 24 hours, if you don't know yet :)

When it is 1:00, how many hours passed? 1 hour!

When it is 20:00, how many hours passed? 20 hours!

When its 24:00 (or 0:00), 24 hours passed already. But the day consist of 24 hours, so how there can be 24:19? It would be nineteenth minute of... **25th** hour... wat?

Answer (score 0):

Format for time is : HH:MM:SS  (H->Hour, M->Minutes, S->Seconds)
Try inserting something like

00:60:00 then
00:61:00

I am sure it will get converted to 01:01:00 as 61 mins means 1 hour and 1 min.
So same is the case with 24:19:01.
If the format would have been like DD:HH:MM:SS where D-> Number of days 
then 24:19:01 would have been converted to 01:00:19:01.